# how to move view from mapkit in xcode

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I use `mapkit` framework in my app and I want move in my app with code **not finger**.
I create mapView and 4 buttons (up - bottom - left - right) that these buttons doing these works (go to top - go to bottom - ...) with code.

important notice : my friends I want moving specific part view (for example my specific part has 320px width and 100px height)

So I want when click top button my part (320*100) of my map move to top...

please guide me...

Comment: So each button moves to a different, but each static, lat-long rect?

Comment: yes my friend each button moves to a different but when click top button my map go to top (for example going top 100px).

Comment: @Wain please guide me I so confused and so tired!!!

Answer (score 2):

If each button moves to a static position (and zoom) on the map then you can create a configuration something like:

- each button has an associated `MKMapRect` / `MKCoordinateSpan`
- when a button is tapped, get the associated area information
- call `setVisibleMapRect:animated:` on the map view

Note that you don't really need to think in terms of top / bottom, just specify exactly what area the map view should be displaying following selection of each button.

Alternatively, if the zoom level never changes, you can use `setCenterCoordinate:animated:`. Let's take this option for an example and using `CLLocation` to make life easy:

Create an array containing your locations:

```
configArray = @[ topLocation, bottomLocation, .... ];
```

Create the buttons, and set the tag of each to the appropriate array index:

```
topButton.tag = 0;
bottomButton.tag = 1;
...
```

When a button is tapped, get the tag to get the location to update the map:

```
CLLocation *location = self.configArray[sender.tag];
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Comment: my friend I understand a little but if you explain me with code I so thank you ...